# Selendroid : Can not launch app on smartphone

Tags: java, selenium, selendroid

I started the Selendroid server:

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies -app Guru99App.apk
```

The test App Guru99App.apk is signed.

Then I ran this code in Eclipse:

```
import io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidConfiguration;
import io.selendroid.standalone.SelendroidLauncher;
import io.selendroid.common.SelendroidCapabilities;
import io.selendroid.client.SelendroidDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SelendroidTest1 {
    private static SelendroidLauncher selendroidServer = null;
    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    @Test
    public void selendroidTest() throws Exception {                                               
        System.out.print("Start executing test");   
        SelendroidConfiguration config = new SelendroidConfiguration();
        selendroidServer = new SelendroidLauncher(config);
        selendroidServer.launchSelendroid();
        DesiredCapabilities caps = SelendroidCapabilities.android();
        driver = new SelendroidDriver(caps);                                 
    }


    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

My Smartphone is connected, I checked with 'adb devices' as well,  but I keep getting this Exception:
'No devices are found. This can happen if the devices are in use or no device screen matches the required capabilities.'

I also tried starting the server with:

```
java -jar selendroid-standalone-0.17.0-with-dependencies -aut Guru99App.apk
```

I assumed that the problem is due to an unsupported version of Android, so I tried this :

```
SelendroidCapabilities caps = new SelendroidCapabilities("com.guru99app:1.0");  
caps.setPlatformVersion(io.selendroid.common.device.DeviceTargetPlatform.ANDROID10);    
caps.setEmulator(false);                   
driver = new SelendroidDriver(caps);
```

This also did not help.
I am using a Motorola Moto one.
How can I solve this?

Comment: I just checked my phone, it is running Android 9, that's Api level 28 ricght? So I guess that is the reason I can not launch the app on my real device, simce senledroid supports Api level 10 to 19 only?